# How to pass a object in js funcion as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery foreach appended list in a table. what I want is to pass the full object that I am getting from an ajax success function.but when I try to pass the Object as a parameter to a different JS function, the parameter gets undefined.

this is my appended table:

```js
$.ajax({

  type: "post",
  url: "@Url.Content("~/Estimate/GetOffsetLetterHeadCost
  ")",
  data: $('#OffLetterHeadForm').serialize(),
  datatype: "json",
  traditional: true,
  success: function(data) {

    var Json = data;

    $.each(Json, function(index, obj) {


      var row = '<tr>' + '<td style="padding:10px" > <b style="font-size:18px">' + obj.VendorName + '</b>  </td>  ' + '<td><label  id="machineId' + index + '">' + obj.MachineName + '  < / label > < /td > ' + '<td> <input type="button"   value="Order" id="btn' + index + '"onclick = "SaveOffsetOrder(obj)" / > < /td></tr > ';

      $("#AllVendorsList").append(row);

    });

  }
});


function SaveOffsetOrder(obj) { // here i am getting obj undefined
  // do something with obj
}
```

```html
<table id="AllVendorsList" class="table table-striped table-hover  " style="font-size:14px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS'"></table>
```

please help..Thanks

Comment: `obj` have different scopes the way you are using them. You probably need to pass it serialised or as `data-attribute`.

Comment: @lain i didn't get..please ellaborate

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `onclick` as `onclick='SaveOffsetOrder(` + JSON.stringify(obj) + `)'` notice that single quote before `SaveOffsetOrder` and `JSON.stringify(obj)` which will create `onclick` function as `SaveOffsetOrder({"name":"test"})` which is correct.

```js
var obj = {name: 'test'};
var html = `<input type="button"   value="Order" id="btn' + index + '" 
                  onclick='SaveOffsetOrder(` + JSON.stringify(obj) + `)' />`;
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = html;

function SaveOffsetOrder(obj){
  console.log(obj);
}
```

```html
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how stringifying a variable will suddenly stop it from being `undefined`. There's no reason at all why you shouldn't be able to pass an object, and why you would be forced to strigify it. There's more to it than that.

Comment: @SHK that is just an example to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: sir,how to keep SaveOffsetOrder in single quotes its giving error..i am new to JS

Comment: its giving error,unexpected end of input in the definition of function

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using onclick use bind which will make life pretty much easier. E.g.

```
'<td> <input type="button"   value="Order" id="btn' + index + '" 
      / > < /td></tr > '
$("#AllVendorsList").append(row);
$("#btn" + index).bind("click",{obj:obj},SaveOffsetOrder);

function SaveOffsetOrder(e){
 console.log(e.data.obj);//this will return your object.
}
```

Comment: Yes. This sounds more like it.

Comment: @UllasHunka,where i will use this ...$("#btn" + index).bind("click",{obj:obj},SaveOffsetOrder);  outside the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

it's easy to mess up variable and string/text within quotation, so colors will help a lot. make sure all variable 'pop out' more.

if still doesn't work, switch all single quotes to double, and replace all double quotes in position of single quote. or, discard and just use selector later in script rather than using onclick property

EDITED (added escape characters in function parameter `\'` )

```
<html>
<body>
    The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
<script>
    var obj = "hello world";
    var row = '<tr>\
        <td style="padding:10px" >\
            <b style="font-size:18px">'+obj+'</b>\
        </td>\
        <td>\
            <label id="machineId'+obj+'">'+obj+'</label>\
        </td>\
        <td>\
            <input type="button" value="Order" id="btn'+obj+'" onclick = "SaveOffsetOrder(\'' + obj +' \')"/>\
       </td>\
    </tr>';

    document.body.innerHTML = row;
    function SaveOffsetOrder(obj){
        alert(obj);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

----before (only works for integers?)-----

```
var row = '<tr>\
    <td style="padding:10px" >\
        <b style="font-size:18px">'+obj.VendorName+'</b>\
    </td>\ 
    <td>\
        <label id="machineId'+index+'">'+obj.MachineName+'</label>\
    </td>\ 
    <td>\
        <input type="button" value="Order" id="btn'+index+'" onclick = "SaveOffsetOrder(' + obj + ')"/>\
    </td>\
</tr>';
```

Comment: i  just want to keep onclick function to be in a single quotes

Comment: @SHK i don't really get what you mean. is obj string? maybe try escaping characters using `\'` or `\"`. i've edited my answer